# How to convert checkerboard coordinates to the corresponding row and column number in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, coordinates, hashtable

This is my first time working with java so please bear with me. So imagine an 26x26 checkerboard (or chessboard). I need to know how to properly convert a checkerboard's coordinates to the corresponding row and column number. For example, z19 corresponds to a piece on the 26th column and 19th row. I've already gotten most of the code down using a hash table but the trouble i'm having is when I input a double digit number, the output i get are the two digits, BUT separated. For example:

```
Input: z19
Output:
26
1
9
```

How can i fix this issue? 
Here is my method:

```
public static void hash(String coordinates){

        HashMap hash = new HashMap();
        hash.put("a", 1);
        hash.put("b", 2);
        hash.put("c", 3);
        hash.put("d", 4);
        hash.put("e", 5);
        hash.put("f", 6);
        hash.put("g", 7);
        hash.put("h", 8);
        hash.put("i", 9);
        hash.put("j", 10);
        hash.put("k", 11);
        hash.put("l", 12);
        hash.put("m", 13);
        hash.put("n", 14);
        hash.put("o", 15);
        hash.put("p", 16);
        hash.put("q", 17);
        hash.put("r", 18);
        hash.put("s", 19);
        hash.put("t", 20);
        hash.put("u", 21);
        hash.put("v", 22);
        hash.put("w", 23);
        hash.put("x", 24);
        hash.put("y", 25);
        hash.put("z", 26);
        hash.put("1", 1);
        hash.put("2", 2);
        hash.put("3", 3);
        hash.put("4", 4);
        hash.put("5", 5);
        hash.put("6", 6);
        hash.put("7", 7);
        hash.put("8", 8);
        hash.put("9", 9);
        hash.put("10", 10);
        hash.put("11", 11);
        hash.put("l2", 12);
        hash.put("13", 13);
        hash.put("14", 14);
        hash.put("15", 15);
        hash.put("16", 16);
        hash.put("17", 17);
        hash.put("18", 18);
        hash.put("19", 19);
        hash.put("20", 20);
        hash.put("21", 21);
        hash.put("22", 22);
        hash.put("23", 23);
        hash.put("24", 24);
        hash.put("25", 25);
        hash.put("26", 26);
    String word = new String(coordinates);
    char array[] = word.toCharArray();
    for(char c: array) {
        System.out.println(hash.get(String.valueOf(c)));
    }
    }
```

One thing I forgot to mention: I want to also be able to input different coordinate points simultaneously. For example, if I type this in:

```
Input: a4c23d17
```

I want it to output this:

```
1
4
3
23
4
17
```

Comment: FYI,  you have `l2` as a key instead of `12`. This is a great example of the dangers of code repetition, aka copy/paste, aka WET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating the issue. Try this:

```
// split coordinates string into (x, y) pairs by using
// regex lookahead to find the next alphabetical character
for (String coord : "a4c23d17".split("(?=[a-z])")) {
    // subtract the ascii value of 'a' from
    // the first char to get the numeric offset
    System.out.println(coord.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1);
    // parse the remainder as an integer
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(coord.substring(1)));
}
```

Comment: +1 but would be improved by an explanation of how it works since OP is working with java for the first time

Comment: "Your 1:1 coordinate mapping is overcomplicated. Let's use regexes and ASCII-code arithmetic instead!"

Comment: @walen Very clever.

Comment: sweet! how would I go about implementing this if I wanted to let a user input their own coordinates?

Comment: @user5983028 Replace `"a4c23d17"` with your input variable.

Comment: lol thanks for that super fast reply! Yeah I just did that and it totally worked. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

(If you rather doing it your way)

Just use the scanner to make your life easier:

```
 HashMap hash = new HashMap();

 for(int i=1; i < 27; i++){
     hash.put(String.valueOf(60 + i), i);     //61 .. 86 is the ASCII value for a .. z
     hash.put(String.valueOf(i), i);
 }

 String word = new String(coordinates);
 Scanner s = new Scanner(word);

 While(s.hasNext()){
    System.out.println( hash.get(s.nextByte()) );

    if(s.hasNext())
        System.out.println( hash.get(s.nextInt()) );
 }
```